# How to create a global container in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am just starting to learn React, and I would like to know how do you create a global layout container and a global content container. Here is what I am trying to achieve using CSS. BUT I am confused about how to achieve this with React. Would be great for any advice/links to tutorials etc... thanks.

```
.global-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.global-content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you have tagged `styled-components` I'm assuming you're using it too!

```js
//GlobalContainer.js

import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
`

export default function GlobalContainer({ children }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {children}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

```js
// GlobalContent.js

import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
`

export default function GlobalContent({ children }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {children}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great, I will try and use this method of using CSS with styled-components. I'm used to HTML, CSS styling, BUT using React is new,

Answer (score 2):

In the `App.js` put a `div` for your global container and content just as you would in HTML. Note that you have to use `className` instead of `class` to give your `jsx` a `css` class.

```
import "./Styles/index.css"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="global-container">
      <div className="global-content">
          {// Your app goes here
          }

      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me to understand and apply CSS styles to react app.